# Deserialise to anonymous type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to XML deserialize an object of Unknown Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558536/how-to-xml-deserialize-an-object-of-unknown-type)

I've just started playing with serializing and deserializing.

I have a model of type Person, with only 2 properties (Name and Age), I can serialise to XML. When it comes to deserialise, as far as I know, I have to tell the compiler that the type is Person. With the world of generic T, this seems counter productive. I would have thought I could establish the object as a 'InMemoryOnly' object (if you can imagine it) where the object is created at run time, as is it's parameters/fields/properties etc, all based upon the XML. Maybe like an anonymous type; I appreciate that the C# compiler would have to ignore this during design time and that we'd lose intellisense but as all objects are passed to memory any way, I can't see why it would fail at run time. Or maybe this would be possible with Reflection?

Any way, that is what I'm trying to do, deserialise from XML to a generic object. Is this possible with C#?

**EDIT** Just found a dupe so the question now is about why can't C# (.NET) do this? I know the answer is probably "because it doesn't" but my question is COULD it be possible or would be more trouble than it's worth for the programmer?

The reason for this is, as far as I know, to accomplish this means the serialise and de-serialize has to know the type (in this case, Person). So, if the serailise and deserialize happen over WCF (where serialize and serialize happen in different assemblies) then the Person object has to be duplicated (and this is against the DRY principle)

Comment: What would possibly be the advantage of this? Why try to make things needlessly complicated and implicit? In my opinion and experience it is always best to let your code express explicitly what it must do; that is far more readable, understandable and hence maintainable.

Comment: The dupe is no longer relevant. With the new dynamic keyword in .NET 4 this can be achieved. However, how would you use such a type? As it has been soley defined in the XML, you know nothing about it and can't make any use of it, can you?

Comment: So are you wanting to deserialize to an unknown type or one that won't be known until runtime?

Comment: @RoyDictus +1 - I agree but this must mean duplicated code: if I'm serialising in my class using the Person object, pushing it over WCF and deserialising at another destination, I have to also have duplicated code for my Person class; this means if I update my person class I have to do it many times (goes against the DRY principal)

Comment: @NickW - Yes, I have updated my question to explain why

Comment: @DaveRook: Not really, you can share your Person class across projects. Either you put your data classes in a separate project (class library) that you reference in your client and your service, or you create your data classes (such as Person) in one project and then softlink to those files in the other project. Hence, no code duplication required. I do favor the class library approach as it is cleaner.

Comment: WCF message works with Data Contracts. The Data Contracts are not coupled to any class. In your WCF example, WCF Service may actually have some different class name with different property names but the the service will work if the class matches the Data Contract coming over the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WCF sample does not demonstrate a valid reason to do this.
You simply could - and can! - put the Person class in an assembly that is used by both the server and the client. That's how I do it when using WCF.
If you don't want to do this, Visual Studio offers to automatically generate the types used in the service when you add a service reference.
In both cases, you have to update the `Person` class in one place only.